# What is the sense of "bosom labouring" here?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, prepositional-objects, participial-phrases

I've just came a cross the following sentence:

> It seemed to breathe from a **bosom labouring** under the deadliest terror.

and can't puzzle out the meaning of this two words combined together in this sentence. Could someone explain?

Comment: where did you come across this sentence?

Comment: Robert Louis Stevenson. The pavilion on the links.

Comment: The bosom is labouring under some terror. 'bosom' is a noun, 'labouring under ...' is modifying 'bosom'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the full sentence

> "Hush!" said her companion; and there was something in the tone with
>   which the word was uttered that thrilled and rather shook my spirits.
>   It seemed to breathe from a bosom labouring under the deadliest
>   terror; I have never heard another syllable so expressive; and I still
>   hear it again when I am feverish at night and my mind runs upon the
>   old times.

From the statement concerning the expressiveness of the syllable, it is reasonable to interpret '[bosom](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bosom)' in its figurative sense of

> the centre of human feelings

As well as its literal sense of

> the front of a person's chest

'[labour under](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/labor+under)' means

> to be burdened (by) or be at a disadvantage (because of)

Therefore the whole can be taken to mean that the word 'hush!' was uttered as it would be by a person who was terrified to their core. 
By using 'bosom' rather than 'heart' or 'mind' to indicate how the speaker experienced the terror, Stevenson invokes the impression of heavy or stressed breathing while actually talking about the speaker's apparent emotional state.

Comment: Excellent answer, but please add an apostrophe to "speaker's".

Comment: @retron cheers, done.

Answer (score 2):

You’re misparsing this. The syntactic constituent here is *labouring under the deadliest terror*, a right-branching non-finite verb clause modifying the object of the preposition, *bosom*. The noun phrase that constitutes the prepositional object of *under* is all of this:

> (a bosom (labouring under (the deadliest terror)))

Pay close attention to the nesting: you have to analyse this as a right-branching verb clause attached to *bosom*.

Fed into the [online Berkeley Parser tool](http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html), we discover this parse:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP It))
    (VP (VBD seemed)
      (PP (TO to)
        (NP (NN breath)))
      (PP (IN from)
        (NP
          (NP (DT a) (NN bosom))
          (VP (VBG labouring)
            (PP (IN under)
              (NP (DT the) (JJS deadliest) (NN terror)))))))
    (. .)))
```

Which is this graphically:

[image: graphical representation of parse]

Notice how there is no `(bosom labouring)` element there with parens around those two words. That’s what I mean by saying that you are misparsing it.

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive answer. But I still not sure how correctly interpret the whole sentence. From your graph it's obvious that verb clause "labouring under.." is about "bosom" but by reading previous sentences I would say that "labouring under..." more likely describes "breath". What am I missing ?

Comment: @sim 'a bosom heaving under great labor', 'a bosom expanding with each breath', ' a bosom shaking with terror': all these have the same structure 'a bosom' modified by a phrase. 'a bosom that is laboring under the deadliest terror' is an identically meaning phrase - add 'that is' to make it explicit.

Comment: @sim There is no 'breath' in your quotation, the correct word was 'breathe'.

Comment: @Spagirl you are right it's my fault, thanks for correction

Answer (score 0):

Your bosom is your chest area. The verb labour means to make great effort trying to do something. So, what this is saying is that it (words, I assume) seemed to come out of (breath) a chest (the human voice is produced by pushing air out of the lungs) struggling under the deadliest terror. In other words, the terror-stricken person was saying something while breathing heavily.

Comment: I think if "labouring" is about breathing then it has to be comma after bosom, am I right ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, it should be "... bosom, labouring..." in American usage.

Comment: @Davo Not to this American. No, I don't see any need for the comma, and it seems to me to put a pause where I'd never use one naturally.